# Subversion error while updating server

Tags: linux, centos, updates, yum

I have a CentOS server, when I want to update the server via this command:

```
yum update
```

I get this error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package subversion-1.6.12-0.1.el5.rf.x86_64 (which is newer than subversion-1.6.11-11.el5_9.i386) is already installed
  file /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/psvn.el from install of subversion-1.6.11-11.el5_9.i386 conflicts with file from package subversion-1.6.12-0.1.el5.rf.x86_64
  file /usr/share/xemacs/site-packages/lisp/psvn.el from install of subversion-1.6.11-11.el5_9.i386 conflicts with file from package subversion-1.6.12-0.1.el5.rf.x86_64
```

I am trying to clear the yum cache too but I have this problem yet

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a newer version of subversion that the subversion that currently exists in the Centos base Repo. Would you be okay with uninstalling your current version of subversion and re-installing  the current version of subversion? If yes then the commands you would want to run are the following:

```
yum erase subversion
yum update
```